# List all aws-lambda pre-built libraries & modules for nodejs

Tags: aws-lambda

aws documentation indicate that aws-sdk comes by default on all lambda runtimes (obviously) ... also, many post indicates that ImageMagick is also pre-built and ready to use,  but this do not appears on the official documentation (or I didn't found it)

I was searching a lot but didn't found a list off all libraries /modules or extra functionalities included by dafault on Lambda so I do not need to build it by myself. do you know where i can find it?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer:**

ImageMagick (the static binaries) indeed seems to be available on Lambda. I guess image resizing is a very common use case such that they decided to include it on Lambda. They should update that doc page to make it official.

You still have to include the node.js package for interfacing with ImageMagick in your `package.json` though.

---

*Original Answer:*

When in doubt, always use Amazon's official documentation.

[Lambda Execution Environment and Available Libraries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)

I don't think ImageMagick is included by default.

Comment: here it said it is: "Lambda has ImageMagick pre-configured on the compute instances that will be running the Lambda function."  https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/developer/tag/s3/?nc1=h_ls   that's why I think there are more functionalities rather than only aws-sdk

Comment: thank for the update... as image resizing is a common case, there is many other common case like input data validation and there are a few libraries that manage that... or other known libraries like lodash that I think maybe aws support... but there is no more info on the link that you shared.

Comment: I would caution against always assuming certain dependencies to be present unless AWS has clear documentation on it. For best practice, it's always better to control the versions of dependencies that you include anyway.

Comment: You can try using [lambdash](https://github.com/alestic/lambdash) to explore what's available in the container. According to [this probably outdated article](https://alestic.com/2014/11/aws-lambda-environment/), it only bundles `aws-sdk` and `imagemagick` in node_modules. You should probably make your own test to get an updated list or just contact AWS support.

Comment: I have a conundrum with Lambda and Imagemagick. The AMI that AWS advertises as being the AMI that is used in the lambda compute instance does not appear to have imagemagick installed when you create an EC2 instance with it. However when you run a lambda you can load and run imagemagick. So its not clear to me what happens that is different in either case.